# Fieldset height 100% of table cell when content is dynamic

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, height, fieldset

I have the following structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/q9v9j/10/

I'm trying to get the fieldsets to vertically fill their parent table cells.

My understanding is that in order for the fieldset to have height 100% I need to set a fixed height on it's parent.

However the content within each fieldset is generated dynamically, therefore I cannot set a fixed height.

The above jsFiddle works in Chrome, but not IE.

How can I achieve this in IE? I'd prefer a css solution but would also welcome jQuery suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the `td` height as `1px`. I removed it.
Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/q9v9j/13/

Comment: No sorry, I only added the height 1px on the td to specify a fixed height on the parent (which works in Chrome). However IE renders the height 1px literally. Removing the fixed height breaks both IE and Chrome.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have the `fieldset` fill the entire table column, isn't it?

Comment: You need to use `display:inline-block` in the `fieldset` element and set its `height:100%`. Note : For some reason, its not showing correctly on JSFiddle, but if you create an html with same data, it works fine(checked in IE7 and Firefox 15) (no access to chrome) JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/3BDqf/16/

Comment: Yes you're right I want the fieldset to fill the entire column. However your fiddle only works in quirks mode in IE. I need a standards compliant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main element "table" has to have height:100%, then it magically works.

```
See here:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/nGCdx/13/